# How to use mailjet with contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, email, mailjet

I have a word press site in which I am using the mail chimp extension with contact form 7 to send emails. Now I want to remove mail chimp and integrate mail-jet to send emails with that contact form. I have tried using the mail-jet extension but I don't understand how to use it with contact form 7. There is not any other extension like mail-chimp for mail-jet. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You can refer: https://www.mailjet.com/blog/news/email-101-sending-email-using-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: I have tried this but I can't understand how to use this to add the user in particular contact list who fill the form and submit it.

Comment: In document it is clearly mention, you have to manage configuration settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's meant here is that by configuring the mailjet smtp settings you can use contact form 7 to create a contact us form and then be assured that mailjet will do the email transactions for it.